# The sum function isn't universal. So which is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sum

I've recently used the `sum()` function on a `list` of characters. An error occurred:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I've started writing a function for replacement and realised that the problem is that I've initialized a variable for the output to `0` and used a for loop for adding every element. That is probably done in the built-in function. I've realised that a solution is to initialize the before mentioned output variable to `type(arr[0])()`. I want to ask whether is there another built-in function for adding all elements of a list that is meant for all datatypes that support the addition operator.

Thanks for reaching out!

NOTE:
In the `help(sum)` it is clearly pointed out that the function is specifically for numerical values.

Comment: You can use sum on non-numerical values, but you can't combine them, just like you can't write: `"5" + 5`. For example: `sum(["a", "b", "c"])` will yield `"abc"`.

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to add integers and strings. It’s not clear what it should do with something like `5 + “t”`. It would help people give you better advice if you showed the data you wish to sum.

Comment: @Yuval.R nope. Your example throws exactly the TypeError OP is seeing.

Comment: Have you considered posting code and the resulting errors instead of just describing them?

Comment: @Yuval.R: I get the same error as the op for: `sum(["a", "b", "c"])`

Comment: If you want faster code, don't use Python. Why are you worrying about performance? If this is a performance question, please answer the basic performance question;: How many items do you process? How long does it take? How long do you expect it to take? What are your machine specs?

Comment: Too all the guys who noted that my example doesn't work, you're right, I have no idea why I remembered it works...

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `functools.reduce()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `functools.reduce()` is what you're looking for.

```
import functools
import operator

functools.reduce(operator.add, ["a", "b"])  # -> "ab"
functools.reduce(operator.add, [1, 2])      # -> 3
```

PS: if you look at the [Python manual entry for `reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce), they show what the implementation is "roughly equivalent to". Notice how the initial value is the first item itself by default, thus removing the problem of determining its type altogether. The consequence, however, is that if you call it with an empty list, you have to provide `initializer` or get a `TypeError`.

Comment: You are right, this is even better for that type of function, because my idea needed the datatype to have a constructor that can take no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all things by converting them into a string:

```
things = [1, 3.14, "string", object()]
result = ""
for thing in things:
    result += str(thing)
print(result)
```